# Deprecated: mktime(): The is_dst parameter is deprecated

Tags: php, function, date, mktime, date-math

**standard function:** ( see on [codepad](http://codepad.org/jP8R6iLv) )

```
<?php

$start_time_o = "18:00";
$end_time_o = date("H:i");

function get_time_difference(){

    global $start_time_o, $end_time_o;

    $start_time = explode(":", $start_time_o);
    $end_time = explode(":", $end_time_o);

    $start_time_stamp = mktime($start_time[0], $start_time[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $end_time_stamp = mktime($end_time[0], $end_time[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $time_difference = $end_time_stamp - $start_time_stamp;

    return gmdate("H:i", $time_difference); 
}

echo get_time_difference();

?>
```

**modified function:** ( see on [codepad](http://codepad.org/K1oZ5WQa) )

```
<?php

$start_time_o = "18:00:01";
$end_time_o = date("H:i:s");

function get_time_difference(){

    global $start_time_o, $end_time_o;

    $start_time = explode(":", $start_time_o);
    $end_time = explode(":", $end_time_o);

    $start_time_stamp = mktime($start_time[0], $start_time[1], $start_time[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $end_time_stamp = mktime($end_time[0], $end_time[1], $end_time[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $time_difference = $end_time_stamp - $start_time_stamp;

    return gmdate("H:i:s", $time_difference); 
}

echo get_time_difference();

?>
```

the first function works without any errors or notices.

the modified function gives the message:

```
Deprecated: mktime(): The is_dst parameter is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 13
Deprecated: mktime(): The is_dst parameter is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14
```

i don't know why i receive the message only at the modified function?
what's wrong in here?

Comment: You are using one argument too many on the `mktime()` function

Answer (score 3):

use `strtotime`

like

```
$someString = '10/10/2012 4:34 pm';  
date_default_timezone_set('American/New_York');
$timestamp = strtotime($someString);
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: +1 Much better way to achieve what the question is trying to do :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use a simpler way to do this try using [`DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('18:00:01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('H:i:s');
?>
```

Here it is as a function which may make it easier for you to use:

```
<?php
function diff($first_datetime, $second_datetime = "now")
{
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($first_datetime);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($second_datetime);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    return $interval->format('H:i:s');
}

// One of the date/time parameters is now so 
// we only  have to pass one parameter
echo diff('18:00:01');

// Neither parameter is now
echo diff('18:00:01', '20:00:00');
?>
```

Comment: +1 Another good answer, but may be too advanced for @bernte as it uses objects :-)

Comment: hi john.. i tried your small code :) but i don't receive the result i want.. i get the difference in +1h.. and -1h format.. but i need the absolute time

Comment: for echo diff('18:00:01', '17:00:01'); i get 01:00:00 but i need 23:00:00. is that possible?

Comment: Just switching the order of the parameters *should* do it

Comment: no that doesn't work.. i get the same result (01:00:00). 18:00:01 is today and 17:00:01 is yesterday

Answer (score 2):

You are using one too many arguments on the `mktime()` function. Remove one of the zeros, like this:

```
$start_time_stamp = mktime($start_time[0], $start_time[1], $start_time[2], 0, 0, 0);
$end_time_stamp = mktime($end_time[0], $end_time[1], $end_time[2], 0, 0, 0);
```

**This is what is causing your issue, however as @NullPointer has pointed out in his answer, there is a much more efficient and better way to achieve this. Use his solution!**